# Trigonometric inequality on a average, tight Cauchy-Schwarz and Gram's inequality

Tags: measure-theory, trigonometry, average, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Given a function $f(x,t)$ and an average measure defined as $\langle \bullet \rangle \equiv \int_\infty dx \, g(x) f(x)$, where $g(x)$ is time-independent and normalized such that $\int g^2(x)dx=1$, I want to show that 
\begin{equation}
\left \langle \frac{d \cos^2f}{dt} \right \rangle^2 \leq ?  \left \langle \cos^2f \right \rangle   \left \langle \sin^2f \right \rangle  \left \langle \left( \frac{d \cos^2f}{dt} \right)^2\right \rangle 
\end{equation}

The function $f$ is well behaved, and we can define a bound to its time-evolution. Hence the problem comes to solving
\begin{equation}\label{question}
\left \langle  \cos f \sin f  \right \rangle^2 \leq ?  \left \langle \cos^2f \right \rangle   \left \langle \sin^2f \right \rangle  \left \langle  \cos^2f \sin^2 f \right \rangle \quad \quad (1)
\end{equation}

Using Cauchy-Schwarz and the Gram's inequality, I have so far 
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\left \langle  \cos^2 f \sin^2 f  \right \rangle \left \langle  \cos f \sin f  \right \rangle^2   \\
&\leq& \left \langle  \cos^2 f \sin^2 f  \right \rangle \left \langle  \cos f \sin f  \right \rangle^2 + \left \langle \left( \cos f \langle \cos f \sin^2 f \rangle - \sin f \langle \cos^2 f \sin f \rangle\right)^2 \right \rangle \\
&\leq &\left \langle \cos^2f \right \rangle   \left \langle \sin^2f \right \rangle  \left \langle  \cos^2f \sin^2 f \right \rangle
\end{eqnarray}

I need a tighter bound to prove the sign in Eq. (1).

Any suggestion is welcomed!